# Plus in two dimensional array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a code like that

```
my @table1 = ([0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]);

$table1[0][1] = $table1[0][1] + 1;

for(my $k=0;$k<4;$k++){
    for(my $l=0;$l<6;$l++){
        print "$table1[k][l] ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

But i can't a true response from the writing section. It turns all "0".

How can i fix that? Thanks for your helping.

Comment: You should `use strict;`

Comment: Yes i used to. But it's just a mistake what i can't see. My fault. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot two `$`'s:

```
print "$table1[$k][$l] ";
```

Standard recommendation here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at the beginning of your script, and perl itself tells you about this mistake...

Comment: What a silly mistake :) Thank you for your help I was stuck there.